# using 3 monitors with macmini (2018)

Tags: display, mac-mini

I'm thinking of getting the 2018 mac mini(32 gb of ram) with 3 monitors, one 32 4k, the second 27" HD(1920) and the third 23" (1920), it will be possible without lag and an external egpu?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mac mini - Technical Specifications](https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/) webpage:

> ### Video Support
>
> #### Support for the following combination of maximum concurrent display setups:
>
> - Up to three displays:
>
> Two displays with 4096x2304 resolution at 60Hz connected via Thunderbolt 3 plus one display with 4096x2160 resolution at 60Hz connected via HDMI 2.0
>
> or
>
> - Up to two displays:
>
> One display with 5120x2880 resolution at 60Hz connected via Thunderbolt 3 plus one display with 4096x2160 resolution at 60Hz connected via HDMI 2.0

So, yes, your model of Mac mini supports using three displays concurrently without using an external GPU.